# How do hotels set up for the 2nd Seder?

Tags: melacha-creative-work, yom-tov, hachana-prep-for-weekday

I had heard from several rabbanim that one is not allowed to prepare anything on the 1st day of Pesach for the 2nd day (*hachanah*). This includes Seder preparations.

I'm curious how they do this in hotels during Pesach where there are hundreds of people there. It takes about an hour to set up all the place settings; and I'm not including food warm-up, which takes a while as well. The dining room is fully set by the time people enter it, about 20 - 30 minutes after the 2nd day of Yom Tov begins.

Are the tables set by Gentiles, exclusively? If so, there is no problem with *Amira Lenachri* or benefitting from a Gentiles work (in this case, *hachanah* on Yom Tov?)

Please explain how hotels get around the *hachanah* problem.

Comment: By chance, do you have a written source for this practice?

Answer (score 8):

The *Maharsham* (*Daas Torah* 444:1) and others (based on the *Pri Megadim*) allow instructing a gentile to perform *hachanah* and others allow doing so if necessary for a *mitzvah*, which would presumably include preparing for a *yom tov seudah*. See [here](http://din.org.il/2011/01/14/%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C-%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%91%D7%96%D7%94-%D7%9E/) (including the comment for more sources) and [here](http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/hachanah_in_a_pesach_hotel.php).